# How can I set up a button to add & transform data from the clipboard?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a button on an access form that would copy the information of an excel file, and paste it into an access table that looks like this:

[image]

An example excel file I'm trying to paste from is 
[here on this site](https://sss2018.wixsite.com/accessquestion) (click the excel icon).

The problem is that the format on the data of the excel file is completely off, it doesn't align with how I set up my data labels on the Access table. What I want to do is select the Excel data and copy it, then in access use a button that, on click, gets the information from the clipboard, arranges the rows, eliminates extra spaces and arranges columns etc, and puts the information on the Access table in an orderly manner.

I just started learning vba and I have been trying everything I can think of for days now without success, meaning that I am able to get the data in the way I want to into the clipboard but I cannot get it from the clipboard into the access able. 
Please help! Thank you!

Code I have so far

```
Sub cmdCopy_Click()
Dim objData As New MSForms.DataObject

Dim strText As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim ComponentNumber As Integer
Dim ComponentText As String
Dim ComponentBlock(100) As Long
Dim ComponentContent(100) As String
Dim ComponentCount As Integer
Dim ComponentStart As Long
Dim ComponentEnd As Long 
Dim ComponentLength As Integer
Dim SearchChar As String
Dim Component(100, 2) As Long
Dim LineArray(8000) As String
Dim labname As Integer
Dim TestString As String
Dim ReferenceRangeStart As Integer
Dim Position As String
Dim ColumnDatePosition(6) As Integer
Dim ColumnDateCount As Integer
Dim ComponentBlockLength As Long
Dim PreliminaryArray(10000, 10) As Variant
ComponentCount = 0
'get text from Clipboard
objData.GetFromClipboard
strText = objData.GetText()
 ' replace double empty lines with single
StrLength = Len(strText)
strText = Replace(strText, Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10), Chr(13) & 
Chr(10))
For i = 10 To StrLength
If Mid(strText, i, 9) = "Component" Then
ComponentBlock(ComponentCount) = i
ComponentCount = ComponentCount + 1
i = i + 9
End If
Next i
 ' separate clipboard into component blocks
ComponentStart = 1
For i = 0 To ComponentCount - 1
ComponentContent(i) = Mid(strText, ComponentStart, ComponentBlock(i) - ComponentStart)
ComponentStart = ComponentBlock(i)
Next i
TotalBlocks = i - 1
' determine column spacing
SearchChar = Chr(13) & Chr(10)
ArrayLength = 0
For k = 0 To TotalBlocks
Next k
ComponentLength = InStr(ComponentContent(k), SearchChar) + 1
'Determine where Reference Range starts
ReferenceRangeStart = InStr(1, ComponentContent(k), "Latest")
'Determine position of each date column
ColumnDateCount = 0
For m = 0 To 6
ColumnDatePosition(m) = 0
Next m
ComponentLength = InStr(ComponentContent(k), SearchChar) + 1
'Determine where Reference Range starts
ReferenceRangeStart = InStr(1, ComponentContent(k), "Latest")
'Determine position of each date column
ColumnDateCount = 0

For i = ReferenceRangeStart + 7 To ComponentLength - 10
Position = Mid(ComponentContent(k), i, 6)
If Position Like "##/##/" Then
ColumnDatePosition(ColumnDateCount) = i
i = i + 6
ColumnDateCount = ColumnDateCount + 1
End If
If Position Like "#/##/#" Then
ColumnDatePosition(ColumnDateCount) = i
i = i + 6
ColumnDateCount = ColumnDateCount + 1
End If
If Position Like "#/#/##" Then
ColumnDatePosition(ColumnDateCount) = i
i = i + 6
ColumnDateCount = ColumnDateCount + 1
End If
If Position Like "##/#/#" Then
ColumnDatePosition(ColumnDateCount) = i
i = i + 6
ColumnDateCount = ColumnDateCount + 1
End If
   Next i
'Debug.Print ColumnDatePosition(0), ColumnDatePosition(1), ColumnDatePosition(2), ColumnDatePosition(3), ColumnDatePosition(4), ColumnDatePosition(5)
'Length of component line is ComponentLength
'Reference Range starts at ReferenceRangeStart
'ColumnDateCount indicates how many date columns of labs are present
'ColumnDatePosition(ColumnDateCount) stores the date positions
'ComponentContent(ComponentCount) represents the text block for each component block
'Mid(ComponentContent(0), ColumnDatePosition(1), 10), Mid(ComponentContent(0), ColumnDatePosition(2), 10), Mid(ComponentContent(0), ColumnDatePosition(3), 10)

LineLength = Len(ComponentContent(k)) / ComponentLength
For i = 1 To LineLength
If Mid(ComponentContent(k), (i - 1) * ComponentLength + 1, 9) <> "Component" 
And Not Asc(Mid(ComponentContent(k), (i - 1) * ComponentLength + 1, 1)) = 32 
Then
        j = 0
        Do While ColumnDatePosition(j + 1) > 0
        If Asc(Mid(ComponentContent(k), ColumnDatePosition(j) + (i - 1) * ComponentLength, 1)) <> 32 Then
            'ArrayLength,0 is component(lab name)
            PreliminaryArray(ArrayLength, 0) = Mid(ComponentContent(k), (i - 1) * ComponentLength + 1, ReferenceRangeStart - 1)
            DateLength = ColumnDatePosition(j + 1) - ColumnDatePosition(j)
            ReferenceLength = ColumnDatePosition(0) - ReferenceRangeStart
            'ArrayLength,1 is reference range
            PreliminaryArray(ArrayLength, 1) = Mid(ComponentContent(k), ReferenceRangeStart + (i - 1) * ComponentLength, ReferenceLength)
            'ArrayLength,2 is date
            PreliminaryArray(ArrayLength, 2) = Mid(ComponentContent(k), ColumnDatePosition(j), 10)
            PreliminaryArray(ArrayLength, 2) = CDate(PreliminaryArray(ArrayLength, 2))
            'ArrayLength,3 is lab value
            PreliminaryArray(ArrayLength, 3) = Mid(ComponentContent(k), ColumnDatePosition(j) + (i - 1) * ComponentLength, DateLength)
            ArrayLength = ArrayLength + 1
        End If
        j = j + 1
        Loop
        If Asc(Mid(ComponentContent(k), ColumnDatePosition(j) + (i - 1) * ComponentLength, 1)) <> 32 Then
        PreliminaryArray(ArrayLength, 0) = Mid(ComponentContent(k), (i - 1) * ComponentLength + 1, ReferenceRangeStart - 1)
        PreliminaryArray(ArrayLength, 1) = Mid(ComponentContent(k), ReferenceRangeStart + (i - 1) * ComponentLength, ColumnDatePosition(0) - ReferenceRangeStart)
        PreliminaryArray(ArrayLength, 2) = Mid(ComponentContent(k), ColumnDatePosition(j), 10)
        PreliminaryArray(ArrayLength, 2) = CDate(PreliminaryArray(ArrayLength, 2))
        PreliminaryArray(ArrayLength, 3) = Mid(ComponentContent(k), ColumnDatePosition(j) + (i - 1) * ComponentLength, ComponentLength - ColumnDatePosition(j) - 2)
        ArrayLength = ArrayLength + 1
        End If
End If
```

Next i

Comment: Share the code what you have tried until now.

Comment: What does 'without success' mean - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? What effort have you done to debug? You need to describe specific issue, not just post code asking 'what is wrong'. Review code from this site for examples http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_MainPage.htm

Comment: With the code above, I am able to get the data the way I want into the clipboard but I cannot figure out how to get it from the clipboard into my access table.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to a monospaced font reveals that data is transposed into 4 space delimited columns.

[image]

Using `Range.TextToColumns()` to split and `WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.UsedRange.Value)` to transpose the data, we get a standard table with 11 columns by 3 rows.

```
+------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------------------+----------------------+------------------+---------------+-------------------------+-----------------+----------------------+------------------------+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
|       Component        | Color, Urine | Appearance, Urine | Specific Gravity, Urine | Urine pH  | Protein Semiquant, UA | Glucose, Urine, Semiquant | Ketones, Urine, Qualitative | Bilirubin, Urine, Qualitative | Hemoglobin Pigments, Urine | Nitrite, Urine | Leukocyte Esterase, Urine | Urobilinogen, Urine | White Blood Cells, Urine | White Blood Cells, UA | Red Blood Cells, Urine | Red Blood Cells, UA | Hyaline Casts, Urine | Granular Casts, Urine | Epithelial Cells, Urine | Bacteria, Urine | Mucous Threads, Urine | Crystals, Urine | White Blood Cell Count | Red Blood Cell Count |    Hemoglobin    |  Hematocrit   | Mean Corpuscular Volume | Mean Corpus Hgb | Mean Corpus Hgb Conc | RBC Distribution Width |  Platelet Count   | Mean Platelet Volume | Nucleated RBC Number | Neutrophil %  | Lymphocytes % |  Monocyte %  |
+------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------------------+----------------------+------------------+---------------+-------------------------+-----------------+----------------------+------------------------+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
| Latest Ref Rng & Units |              |                   | 1.003 - 1.030           | 4.6 - 8.0 | Negative              | Negative mg/dL            | Negative                    | Negative                      | Negative                   | Negative       | Negative                  | 0.2 - 1.0 mg/dL     | 0 - 5 /[HPF]             | 0 - 27 /uL            | 0 - 5 /[HPF]           | 0 - 27 /uL          | 0 - 1 /[LPF]         | None seen /[LPF]      | /[HPF]                  | None-few /[HPF] | None-few /[LPF]       | None-few /[HPF] | 4.50 - 11.00 K/cu mm   | 4.00 - 5.20 M/cu mm  | 12.0 - 15.0 g/dL | 36.0 - 46.0 % | 80.0 - 100.0 fL         | 26.0 - 34.0 pg  | 31.0 - 37.0 g/dL     | 11.5 - 14.5 %          | 150 - 350 K/cu mm | 9.2 - 12.7 fL        | 0.00 - 0.01 K/cu mm  | 40.0 - 70.0 % | 24.0 - 44.0 % | 2.0 - 11.0 % |
| 12/19/2016             | Yellow       | Clear             | 1.012                   | 6         | Negative              | Negative                  | Negative                    | Negative                      | Small (A)                  | Negative       | Moderate (A)              | <=1.0               | 0                        | 1                     | 1                      | 3                   | 0                    | 0                     | <1                      | None            | Rare                  | None            |                        |                      |                  |               |                         |                 |                      |                        |                   |                      |                      |               |               |              |
| 1/24/2017              |              |                   |                         |           |                       |                           |                             |                               |                            |                |                           |                     |                          |                       |                        |                     |                      |                       |                         |                 |                       |                 | 1.82 (L)               | 4.71                 | 12.6             | 39.3          | 83.4                    | 26.8            | 32.1                 | 13.1                   | 165               | 12.5                 | 0                    | 42.4          | 37.9          | 16.5 (H)     |
|                        |              |                   |                         |           |                       |                           |                             |                               |                            |                |                           |                     |                          |                       |                        |                     |                      |                       |                         |                 |                       |                 |                        |                      |                  |               |                         |                 |                      |                        |                   |                      |                      |               |               |              |
|                        |              |                   |                         |           |                       |                           |                             |                               |                            |                |                           |                     |                          |                       |                        |                     |                      |                       |                         |                 |                       |                 |                        |                      |                  |               |                         |                 |                      |                        |                   |                      |                      |               |               |              |
+------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------------------+----------------------+------------------+---------------+-------------------------+-----------------+----------------------+------------------------+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
```

### Code

```
Sub RealignData()
    Dim data As Variant
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        .UsedRange.TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(79, 1), Array(128, 1), Array(154, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        data = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.UsedRange.Value)
        .UsedRange.ClearContents
        Range("A1").Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)).Value = data

    End With
End Sub
```

This should make the data easier to work with.  As far as getting it into Access there are better way then copy and paste.  I recommend learning how to use `Adodb.Recordset.AddNew`.